# Display Image in Power View and Power BI

Tags: binary-data, powerpivot, powerview, powerbi

I need to create a report in power view where I need to display images in tile. I have found one solution to do so, to store the images as a binary data in data model table using the following link

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2014/09/adding-data-bound-images-to-power-view-with-power-query/comment-page-1/#comment-87049

I tried this but still not able to show the images, I am getting only Image icon not the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

I hit an issue that seems to be identical to yours. I just saw camera icons in Power View in Excel and standalone Power View on SharePoint. One of the Microsoft product team has indicated that there is a known issue with loading images into Power View using Power Query and PowerPivot in Excel 2013. See Miguel Llopis' answer here on April 27th:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/09/03/7-new-updates-in-power-query.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage
It appears that using a url (external site or SharePoint site) or loading to the data model via SQL Server may be the only options for now to display images in power view. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Images-in-Power-View-84e91b90-b1da-4913-83d6-beada5591fce?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA) for more information.